# Make Django admin documentation accessible

Tags: django, security, configuration, documentation

I would like to know if there is a way I can make admin documentation (Django) for my project accessible to other users, but at the same time not giving them access to admin database.

Answer (score 1):

I've submitted a patch to limit the documentation for staff users. If superusers can access the Foo and Bar applications and regular staff users can only access Foo, only the documentation for Foo will show up for the latter users. The patch can be found attached here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17905

If you wanted to take it a step further and modify the admindocs views, you can clone the Django repo and add a patch for general users. The [admindocs views file](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admindocs/views.py) contains a number of decorators for @staff_member_required. You could modify this to @login_required if you wanted to show documentation for non-staff users.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with **other users**? If you want to let your *registered users* to access admin documentation, simplest way is making them admin and do nit giving any permissions.So, theycan login to admin, but can only see documentation, since they do not have any module permissions, they will not have access to anything else...